# Google Earth plugins not found on this uri com.google.earth

Tags: android, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I'm trying to show google earth on android device with version 2.3.3

I have tried following code, which ask me "Install Google Earth" and then redirect me to google play store. But, it will show message that "No result found for pname:com.google.earth"

I have also changed uri to "com.google.earth" and "m.google.earth", but both of them are not working.
Thanks for Help.

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // the new intent we will launch 
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(); 

    // send the intent directly to the google earth activity that can 
    // handle search 
    myIntent.setClassName("com.google.earth", 
    "com.google.earth.EarthActivity"); 

    // we are doing a search query 
    myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH); 

    // change this address to any address you want to fly to 
    myIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "2900 Frenchmen Street, New Orleans, LA"); 

        // always trap for ActivityNotFound in case Google earth is not on the device 

        try { 
          // launch google earth and fly to location 
          this.startActivity(myIntent); 
        } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
      showGoogleEarthDialog(); 
    } 
}

 private void showGoogleEarthDialog() { 

    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    downloadDialog.setTitle("Install Google Earth?"); 
    downloadDialog.setMessage("This application requires Google Earth. Would you like to install it?"); 
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new 
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) { 
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.google.earth"); //pname:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent); 
      } 
    }); 
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new 
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {} 
    }); 
    downloadDialog.show(); 
  } 
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: I think it needs a google play services in the device in which you are trying to run your code. So make sure that google play services are installed in device.

Comment: Yes I have google play services installed . App redirects me to  google play but could not able find google.earth in play stor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any ways I found a solution here. basically my intent was not launching the google activity properly. so i have made following code changes and google map shown on activity fine.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

   static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(18.533333, 73.866667);
   static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
   private com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap map;

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:18.533333,73.866667");
    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
    startActivity(it);
 }
}
```